# Calculate a total of an attribute from children and display on view in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to store the location of an item in a building, for example: a box of 100 Pencils is in Storage Room 200 on shelf 1B and 200 biros are in the same room but on shelf 1C.

I want to be able to keep track of the total number of items in each location, so using the above example, Shelf 1B contains 100 items, Shelf 1C contains 200 items and Storage Room 200 will have 300 items.

Here are my classes:

```
class StorageLocation {
    def name
    static hasMany = [storageShelf:StorageShelf]    
}

class StorageShelf {
    def name
    def belongsTo = [storageLocation:StorageLocation]
    static hasMany = [items:Item]    
}

class Item {
    def name
    def quantity
    def belongsTo = [storageShelf:StorageShelf]
}
```

In my view, i want to display a list that looks like this:

- Storage Room 200 (Total: 300 Items)
- - Shelf 1B (Total: 100 Items)
- - - 100 Pencils
- - Shelf 1C (Total: 200 Items)
- - - 200 Biros

My question is what is the best way to add up total quantities for the StorageShelf and StorageLocation each time I want to display one? Ideally, the total value wouldn't be saved to the database.

If i wanted to display a single storageroom at a time, i could just loop through the children and add up the quantities in the controller and return it to the view. But since i'm displaying a list of all the locations and all the shelves, i wouldn't know how to return the total along with the object or even if that is the best way to do it.

Comment: Does `location.storageShelf.items.quantity.flatten().sum()` do it?

Comment: Tim, it seems to! Thats great, i didn't think it was going to be that simple! Many thanks :)

Comment: Cool :-)  Added as an answer!  Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def grandTotal = location.storageShelf.items.quantity.flatten().sum()
```